# Install Keras on Anaconda OSX

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, keras, spyder

I am trying to install keras on an anaconda environment (OSX), because I want to use it with spyder - ipython. To do that I just used `pip install keras` (I already have tensorflow). After the installation when I call python 2.7 from the terminal, keras works fine. But, when I call python 3.5 or spyder and try to import keras I receive:
No module named 'keras'

I assume the issue might be with the PATHS on my MacBook, because `which python` returns

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

while `which python3.5 (or spyder)` returns

```
/Users/georgiospapadopoulos/anaconda/bin/python3.5
/Users/georgiospapadopoulos/anaconda/bin/spyder
```

Also, during `pip install keras` shows that

```
Requirement already satisfied: keras in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

My ~/.bash_profile contains

```
# added by Anaconda3 2.4.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/georgiospapadopoulos/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/georgiospapadopoulos/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib"
export PATH="$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
#PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
PATH="/usr/local/bin/python:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Comment: It would be much easier if you install everything with Anaconda, then this confusion would not happen. I faced a kind of similar problem regarding Anaconda and pip. I had installed Keras using pip, while Theano and Tensorflow using conda, but when I imported Keras with Tensorflow backend, I was getting errors. So, I uninstalled Keras using pip, and installed it again via conda, and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You are probably mixing up the virtual environments. The best way to handle this is to create a vertual env in Anaconda - say, neural-net-venv, and then open the terminal for that venv, and install keras and other related modules. Then go back to Anaconda dash and select that venv as active environment to work on. Then select Jupyter and Spyder and run your imports.

Note that you also should not mix your Python versions - if you must work on Py2 and Py3 - create separate virtual environments for both, install keras, theanos/tensorflows separately in these environments, and you should be good to go.

I have run this setup on MacOS and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

For installing **keras** in `Anaconda`, the best and hassle free way is just use open the `anaconda prompt` and then type:

```
conda install keras
```

Keras runs on either **`tensorflow`** or **`theano`** backends. Once the **keras** install is complete, just open the python shell and type

```
>>>import keras
```

If some error is thrown, then there must be some problem with the backend. So just open the anaconda prompt, and type

```
conda import tensorflow
```

`theano` also can be used. Nevertheless `tensorflow` is the default one.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to insatll keras on Anaconda, tried the above approach, but it still did not work. Specifically, I started Anaconda Navigator and then opened a Mac OS terminal in the base environment. Then I followed the conda install commands for keras and tensorflow. It worked fine for keras. But with tensorflow, I got the following error message:

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
_tflow_select-2.3.0  | 3 KB      | ######################################################### | 100% 

ChecksumMismatchError: Conda detected a mismatch between the expected content and downloaded content
for url 'https://conda.anaconda.org/Anaconda/osx-64/_tflow_select-2.3.0-mkl.tar.bz2'.
  download saved to: /Users/dlin/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/_tflow_select-2.3.0-mkl.tar.bz2
  expected sha256: cc155b27e7bf91ec5370ce1fd2d5fceccbf13ac19706229674ba971fa3751446
  actual sha256: aad248699de112a7a5ead1695dfdf51b5693c2927303844b29dd7d9138dc95b9
```